# Ontology Validator

Tags: validation, owl, ontology

I'm currently doing a research on developing a web based ontology editor. I need to validate that the ontology edited by my tool is consistent and infer knowledge properly. Also, I would like to get some general statistics regarding the ontology. Is there an ontology validator tool available online which I can use for this requirement? OWL 2 Validator and OWL Metrics don't seem to be working anymore.
http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/validator

http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/metrics

Comment: As you are looking for an existing tool, you should ask this on [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, thank you. I will post this question there

Comment: Question has been asked here : http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23056/ontology-validator

Answer (score 1):

Both those tools are just simple web apps using OWLAPI code to carry out the validation. See `Profiles` in [OWLAPI](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/) for how to validate an ontology against a profile, and `OWLReasoner` for ways to test that an ontology is consistent. The second step will also require an `OWLReasoner` implementation to provide the reasoning services. There are numerous Open Source reasoners, e.g., FaCT++, Pellet, Hermit, Konclude, JFact, and various others that can interface with OWLAPI. See [ORE](http://dl.kr.org/ore2015/vip.cs.man.ac.uk_8008/index-2.html) for the most recent competition comparing these reasoners for performance.